# How can I extract certain portions of all lines in a text file?

Tags: python, database, python-requests, extract, readlines

I have a text file that contains several lines of data but I only need to know a little portion of a line. From the initial file, I can narrow it down to the line that contains the information I need but I am unsure how to extract only the necessary data: the contents of mfgcode, modelno and qtyavail.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

The results text file is printed and the response is:

```
['<part branch="1" core="0.00" cost="10.39" deliverytime="1" desc="" errcode="success" kit="" linecode="brand" linenum="1" list="30.08" mfgcode="nike" modelno="1110" qtyavail="40" qtyreq="1" uom="" />']
['<part branch="1" core="0.00" cost="10.66" deliverytime="1" desc="" errcode="success" kit="" linecode="brand" linenum="1" list="30.48" mfgcode="adidas" modelno="1109" qtyavail="209" qtyreq="1" uom="" />']
['<part branch="1" core="0.00" cost="20.17" deliverytime="1" desc="" errcode="success" kit="" linecode="brand" linenum="1" list="30.24" mfgcode="puma" modelno="1108" qtyavail="2" qtyreq="1" uom="" />']
```

How can I only extract the values of mfgcode, modelno and qtyavail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv
import re

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

ff = []
for line in csv_reader:
       ff.append([re.search('mfgcode="(.+?)"', line[0] ).group(1),re.search('modelno="(.+?)"', line[0] ).group(1),re.search('qtyavail="(.+?)"', line[0] ).group(1)])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(ff,columns =['mfgcode','modelno','qtyavail'])
df.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
  mfgcode modelno qtyavail
0    nike    1110       40
1  adidas    1109      209
2    puma    1108        2
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help. How would I save the results for this in a new file?

Comment: @techsandspecs check my answer again. You can save it as csv file in your local directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use print(line[1]) to select custom cell.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. This will only work if the file has some sort of delimiter. This file only has spaces as a delimiter so I'm not sure how to adapt to that. Thank you for your help

Comment: csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='space here') may help

Comment: Haha that was the last option I tried before posting on here. I appreciate the fast responses.